# Rails Syntax Error with `Count`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic to do app and am trying to show the most recent 4 lists on the homepage, then link to "See X more..." at the bottom.  The logic worked perfectly if there were 5 or more lists, but when there were 4 or fewer I would get "See 0 more..." or "See -3 more..." which obviously isn't right, so I added an if statement with the same basic components, but got this very complex syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
...end=( if @my_items.count >= 5 );@output_buffer.safe_append='
...                               ^
/Users/.../app/views/home/index.html.erb:50: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
'.freeze;           end 
                       ^
/Users/.../app/views/home/index.html.erb:103: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting ')'
'.freeze; else 
              ^
/Users/.../app/views/home/index.html.erb:122: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
'.freeze; end 
             ^
/Users/.../app/views/home/index.html.erb:125: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
/Users/.../app/views/home/index.html.erb:127: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

Here's the code, with the problematic line indicated:

```
    <% @top_items.each do |item| %>
      <% if item.user_id == current_user.id %>
      <p>☐ <%= item.name %></p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <p class="text-center">
      <%= if @my_items.count >= 5 %>   <<<<<<THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE
        <%= link_to lists_path do %>See <%= @my_items.count.count - 4 %> More...<% end %>
      <% end %>
    </p>
```

Just to clarify, if I comment out the problem line and it's corresponding `<% end %> the page shows error free. Anyone understand what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<%,` not `<%=`, the statement doesn't return anything.

Comment: Holy lord!  All that for an `=`.  Thank you!

Comment: The equal sign means you want to "echo" out the result. It's not appropriate on an if statement like you have. Same goes for `end`s and `else`s and anything that can't be output (returned).

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the `=` from the `<%=` on `<%= if @my_items.count >= 5 %>` it may be an issue on how ERB handles conditionals and `<%= %>` rather than `<% %>`